# How to get eBay token expiry date using existing eBay token

Tags: java, ebay-api

I have an auth_token of eBay, I want to get the expiration date of this token.

I know its duplicate question, but no answer was provided for that question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23474204/how-to-bring-ebay-token-expiry-date-using-existing-ebay-token

Comment: Creating an explicit duplicate question just because you do not have enough reputation to comment on the existing question is a dubious practice.

Comment: Then What other option I have??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a call to GetTokenStatus. As long as you have passed the token in the `RequesterCredentials.eBayAuthToken` field of the request the date and time that it will expire can be obtained by reading the [ExpirationTime](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetTokenStatus.html#Response.TokenStatus.ExpirationTime) field in the response.

Another way of getting the same information is via the [HardExpirationWarning](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/fieldindex.html#HardExpirationWarning) field that is returned in some of the API operations. For example [AddItem](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/AddItem.html#Response.HardExpirationWarning). This information is returned within the 7-day period prior to a token's expiration.